# Slow network transfer speed to Webpage PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, networking, pagespeed

Good evening,

Currently reading a JSON file through fetch in JS.

I am facing extremely slow resource loading times. WebDev in Chrome shows that I am trying to get a 10.1MB resouce, where 1.9MB was transferred over network. It took around 1.6 minutes to finish the transfer, essentially a speed of about 20KB/s.

Basically just chasing a quick understanding of what is actually happening behind the scenes/what may be the cause of these slow transactions/What I may do to improve this speed.

For additional info, the server is hosted by digitalPacific Australia, accessed from Australia. Internet speed tests are around 11mB/s (4G). Personal server load practically none apart from myself. FTP from server with PHP shows around 2.1MB/s download speed. Dev tools aren't being throttled. According to the waterfall this is the only transaction happening at that time.

Could this be a shared server problem? Is there a way to check if the transfer speed is bottlenecked somewhere?

```
async function fetchAPI(myUrl){
                    let url = myUrl;
                    let result = await fetch(url);
                    if (result.ok) {
                        let data = await result.json()
                        return data;
                    }
                }
```

[image]

Comment: Possibly there is some other throttling going on - the hosting company, or your 4G network, or something in between, throttling HTTP download speeds.  Although that's quite severe. Maybe it's just a bad day. Have you got any kind of logs on your server? Have you asked the hosting company if there are any restrictions which might relate to this scenario? Have you attempted to test this from another device and/or another internet connection? Have you tested it repeatedly over time (preferably some hours/days apart)?

Comment: P.S. `I am trying to get a 10.1MB resouce, where 1.9MB was transferred over network` doesn't entirely make sense. If you only fetch 1.9MB of a 10.1MB total, then why does the network tool show that the download finished successfully with a 200 OK? Seems like you downloaded less then 20% of it... in which case it shouldn't count as complete or successful. Can you clarify?

Comment: Roger, basically just wanted to know if this was unusual, or if there is a reason and it is a common occurrence. Appreciate your reply mate. I'm not 100% sure on what goes on behind the scenes, e.g. a computers ability to write to cache/memory storage.

Comment: Not 100% sure mate, I am grabbing the JSON from the server the webpage is run on so I presume that it is compressed prior to sending maybe? Not exactly sure. When I log the data when it loads, it is all there and works fine :). The cache is reset each test so it obviously can't load from there, but it does tell me if it has done so. The serving of the file is done automatically by Apache.

Comment: `I presume that`...the response headers (visible if you  click on the request in the chrome dev tools) can usually tell you if it's been compressed. It might be configured on the server also...or a CDN if you're using one.

Comment: Do you think the problem is coding related or more the infrastructure.  You may get more help on https://serverfault.com/ if it's an infrastructure problem.